# Confused about how "other" works in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

The netlogo docs give the following example

```
show count turtles-here
=> 10
show count other turtles-here
=> 9
```

and the documentation says the "other" command excludes "this" agent. My question is ... WHICH agent? Seems like this command can be run in the observer context and so no agent. Or at least in this example, the context could be a patch context in which case the "other" would exclude ALL the turtles? Is there some mechanism to set the context for a particular agent? Maybe:

```
ask agent [
   show count other turtles-here
]
```

in which case why didn't the NetLogo code snippet include that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The agent excluded is the agent being asked. `ask`, `ask-concurrent`, and `of` set the context. For example,

```
ask turtle 0 [ show count other turtles ]
```

counts all turtles except for `turtle 0`.

```
ask turtles [ show count other turtles ]
```

iterates over each turtle individually. In each iteration, `other` excludes the current turtle.

`other` never excludes agents of a different type. That is,

```
ask patch 0 0 [ show count other turtles ]
```

will just count all the turtles since none of the turtles are `patch 0 0`.

The agent of the current context can be referred to with [`self`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#self). The agent that `other` excludes will always be `self`. Thus,

```
ask agents [ show count other agents ]
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
ask agents [
  let this-agent self
  show count agents with [ self != this-agent ]
]
```

(note that this can be expressed more succinctly using [`myself`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#myself), but since `myself` is way more confusing, and way worse named, than `other` I'm avoiding it here)

> Seems like this command can be run in the observer context and so no agent.

This is in fact a bug! I've created an issue for it here: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/757

Comment: Thanks so much for verifying what I suspected (and doing it so thoroughly!). I am stunned that other works in observer context. After I posted the question, having nearly answered my own question in the process I was also "bemused" at why the documentation for other has such an incomplete example.

It's a great language/environment but it does have its idiosyncrasies and apparently those idiosyncrasies extend to the documentation too!